# Large serialized file when using pickle

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I have a small problem with the pickle function.
I'm using sci-kit random forest module to train in on a specific data set, and I want to pickle the module after I finish training it, so I won't need to retrain it each time I need a prediction.

A problem that I'm having is that when I use pickle on a machine learning module (specifically Random-Forest) that pickled file is way too big. 
The data set size is about 450 MB, and the pickled module is of the same size so I guess it somehow included the dataset into the serialized object.

I was wondering if there's a way to make the pickled module smaller (like - a lot smaller)?

Comment: Please can you show some example code that shows the approach you're currently trying.